# My copy constructors are wrong. How should they look like?

Tags: c++

I have these two simple classes: CreditCard and Account

```
    #pragma once

    #include<string>

    class CreditCard
    {
    private:
        std::string number;
        int expMonth;
        int expYear;
        int pin;
    public:

        CreditCard():number(""), expMonth(0), expYear(0), pin(0)
        {

        }

        CreditCard(std::string number, int expMonth, int expYear,int pin):number(number), expMonth(expMonth), expYear(expYear), pin(pin)
        {
            if(number.length()!=5)
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Card number must be 5 characters");
            }
            if(expMonth<0 || expMonth>12)
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid expiration month");
            }
            if(expYear<2014 || expYear>2020)
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid expiration year");
            }
            if(pin<1000 || pin>9999)
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("PIN must be between 1000 and 9999");
            }
        }

        CreditCard(const CreditCard &creditCard):number(creditCard.number), expMonth(creditCard.expMonth), expYear(creditCard.expYear), pin(creditCard.pin)
        {

        }   

        CreditCard(CreditCard &&creditCard):number(std::move(creditCard.number)), expMonth(std::move(creditCard.expMonth)), expYear(std::move(creditCard.expYear)), pin(std::move(creditCard.pin))
        {
            creditCard.number="";
            creditCard.expMonth=0;
            creditCard.expYear=0;
            creditCard.pin=0;
        }

        CreditCard& operator = (const CreditCard &creditCard)
        {
            number=creditCard.number;
            expMonth=creditCard.expMonth;
            expYear=creditCard.expYear;
            pin=creditCard.pin;
            return *this;
        }

        CreditCard& operator = (CreditCard &&creditCard)
        {
            if(this!=&creditCard)
            {
                number=std::move(creditCard.number);
                expMonth=std::move(creditCard.expMonth);
                expYear=std::move(creditCard.expYear);
                pin=std::move(creditCard.pin);
                number=creditCard.number;
                expMonth=creditCard.expMonth;
                expYear=creditCard.expYear;
                pin=creditCard.pin;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        std::string getNumber() const
        {
            return number;
        }

        int getExpMonth() const
        {
            return expMonth;
        }

        int getExpYear() const
        {
            return expYear;
        }

        int getPin() const
        {
            return pin;
        }
    };


#pragma once

#include<string>
#include"CreditCard.h"

class Account
{
private:
    std::string number;
    float amount;
    CreditCard creditCard;
public:
    Account():number(""), amount(0), creditCard()
    {

    }

    Account(std::string number, float amount, CreditCard creditCard) : number(number), amount(amount), creditCard(creditCard)
    {

    }

    Account(const Account &account) : number(account.number), amount(account.amount), creditCard(account.creditCard)
    {

    }

    Account(Account &&account) : number(std::move(account.number)), amount(std::move(account.amount)), creditCard(std::move(creditCard))
    {

    }

    Account& operator = (const Account &account)
    {
        number=account.number;
        amount=account.amount;
        creditCard=account.creditCard;      
        return *this;
    }

    Account& operator = (Account &&account)
    {
        if(this!=&account)
        {
            number=account.number;
            amount=account.amount;
            creditCard=account.creditCard;

            account.number="";
            account.amount=0;
            account.creditCard=CreditCard("",0,0,0);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    std::string getNumber() const
    {
        return number;
    }

    float getAmount() const
    {
        return amount;
    }

    void deposit(const float &depositAmount)
    {
        amount+=depositAmount;
    }

    void withdraw(const float &withdrawAmount)
    {
        amount-=withdrawAmount;
    }
};
```

Since i am a beginner, i make mistakes with almost everything i write. What is the right way to write move constructors? How should my 2 move constructors/move assignment operators look like?

Comment: In this case, the right way is to remove their definitions(and the copy constructor and copy assignment operators too) entirely.  The compiler generated versions will do just fine.

Comment: This may be true but as a learning exercise it doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Everything past `pin=std::move(creditCard.pin)` in the move-assignment operator for `CreditCard` should be thrown out. You just moved those members. Referring to them again as a copy-source is *bad*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructors don't need to take any special action, so you can just use the constructor synthesized versions:

```
CreditCard(const CreditCard& creditCard)=default;
CreditCard(CreditCard&& creditCard)=default;
```

and so on.

If you really want to implement them, then this is an example of a hand-made move copy constructor. Note nothing happens in the constructor body.

```
CreditCard(CreditCard&& creditCard)
: 
number(std::move(creditCard.number)), 
expMonth(std::move(creditCard.expMonth)), 
expYear(std::move(creditCard.expYear)), 
pin(std::move(creditCard.pin))
{}
```

Concerning the copy assignment opetators, if you care about exception safety you may want to look into the [copy and swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).

Comment: I understand and you are perfectly right, but i am a beginner and i would like to know what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @JackWilson part of that learning is to know when to *not* write code.

Comment: @JackWillson at a glance, the first thing I notice is that your move copy constructors do some weird stuff in the body of the constructor. See the example I added above.

Comment: I read in many places that after the data of the moved object must be cleared after. I am a bit confused

Comment: @JackWillson: If you were dealing with a class that actually *needed* a user defined move constructor, something like that would be the case.  For example, if you have a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, you would want the move constructor to assign a null pointer to the moved from object, so that it doesn't de-allocate the memory in its destructor.  But that's not the case here.  Instead, you're calling `std::move` on objects which know how to move themselves properly, and so they take care of their own data.

Comment: @JackWillson As mentioned in the comments below the question, everything past `pin=std::move(creditCard.pin)` in the move-assignment operator for `CreditCard` should be thrown out. You just moved those members. Referring to them again as a copy-source is bad.

Answer (score 0):

if your class members are

```
std::string number;
int expMonth;
int expYear;
int pin;
```

and you write a copy constructor as:

```
CreditCard(const CreditCard &creditCard):number(creditCard.number),
 expMonth(creditCard.expMonth), expYear(creditCard.expYear), 
 pin(creditCard.pin){}
```

then this is exactly what compiler would provide if you didn't specify it yourself

you only have to write copy constructor in some special cases, i.e. when you have to dynamically alocate pointer and you don't want then to pointers beeing just 'value' copied in above way

note: you didn't provide initialization of your `std::string` but I don't think it was deliberately